# Removing space in a string without using built in methods

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make/get a new string which doesn't contain spaces.
For example,

```
string1 = "my music is good"
```

should become

```
joinedstring = "mymusicisgood"   #this is the one i want
```

At first i was able to do this by using the built in string method

```
string1 = "my music is good"
joinedstring = string1.replace(" ","")
```

But now I am trying to achieve the same results without any string method, which means I have to make my own function. My thought was to make a loop which searches for the index of the "space" in a string then try to delete indexes to make a new string.
But here comes the problem, strings are immutable so deleting say `del string[index]` doesn't work. Any help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `import string` to make a replacement. [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is a method on any string:

```
>>> string1 = "my music is good"
>>> joinedstring = string1.replace(" ","")
>>> joinedstring
'mymusicisgood'
```

Comment: Thank You, have like a month programming now guess i have to open my book again for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like school homework if you need to "program" built-in functions on your own.
A very simple function for that could look like this:

```
def no_spaces(string1):
    helpstring = ""
    for a in string1:
        if a == " ":
            pass
        else:
            helpstring = helpstring + a
    return helpstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use list comprehension with filter (the `if` part):

```
>>> string1 = "my music is good"
>>> "".join([c for c in string1 if c != " "])
"mymusicisgood"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working function that you can call from your code:

```
def remove_space(old_string):
    new_string = ""
    for letter in old_string:
        if not letter == " ":
            new_string += letter
    print new_string # put here return instead of print if you want

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_space("there was a time")
```